# Modifying many objects in enclosing environment of a function

Tags: r, function

Usually in R a function first creates a new environment and does its stuff inside. I would like to have a function that defines/reinitialize a whole lot of things accessible to the parent environment of a function.

I know I can use the `<<-` operator for specific variables but here I have *a lot* of functions, variables, even environments that are defined and I would like to have the choice with a parameter in the function to use the parent environment or not.

Currently, I'm calling the function and then attaching it's environment if needed as following:

```
init <- function(){
    things <- 0
    ICI <<- environment()
    success <- TRUE
    return(success)
}
init();attach(ICI)
```

It works fine but is their a way to change the current environment of the function to be the parent environment so that I can define a parameter of the function switching on or off this behavior?

Comment: `environment` and `parent.env` both have setters, eg `environment(fun) <- value`; the man page says to be careful with this, though.

Comment: @Neal Fultz Neither allows to set the current environment to be the one of the parent though. `parent.env(ICI) <- ICI` induces a freeze (and infinite recursion I guess).

Comment: `environment(ICI) <- parent.env(ICI)` maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Actually `attach` can be called within the function and the attachment will not be destroyed when returning to the parent environment so the following allows to set back everything in the parent environment:

```
init <- function(transparent=FALSE){
    # compute values
    things <- 0
    success <- TRUE

    # follow "set back variables" argument
    ICI <- environment()
    if(transparent){
        attach(ICI) # everything is transmitted to the parent environment
    }else{
        ICI <<- ICI # only transmit a handle for the environment
    }
    return(success)
}
init();# attach(ICI)
```